# Vacuum expecation value of normal ordered product, Peskin/Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I'm working through Peskin/Schroeder where they treat time ordered product of fields in the interactin picture. The Wick Theorem was introduced as
$$T\{\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)\}=N\{\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)+(\text{all possible contractions})\}$$
where $T$ is the time ordering symbol and $N$ the normal ordering symbol that moves all $a_{\vec{p}}$'s to the left and all $a_{\vec{p}}^\dagger$'s to the right. Applying this to the vacuum, i.e. in calculating
$$\langle0\vert T\{\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)\}\vert 0\rangle$$
it is stated that
$$\langle0\vert N(\text{any operator})\vert 0\rangle=0$$
in order to argue that only fully contracted products of field operators (that are then proportional to the Feynman propagator) survive. I don't understand the last equality or why it should be obvious. I read "any operator" as "any sum of products of $a_{\vec{p}}$'s and $a_{\vec{q}}^\dagger$'s". So isn't for example $$\langle0\vert a_{\vec{p}}a_{\vec{p}}^\dagger\vert 0\rangle\propto\delta^{(3)}(\vec{0})$$ a contradiction to this? Could someone give arguments why the statement in Peskin/Schroeder should be true and where my naive counter example fails? I didn't find an answer to this question given already. If I overlooked something, please hint me towards to the corresponding place. Thank you!

Comment: The normal order brings all the daggers to the left.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I see....my bad. I should take a break, I guess. Thank you!